# In CDH, Dynamic Resource Pool is not running

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Hi I have a one Hadoop Cluster(CDH 5.8.x) and use a cloudera manager to manage hadoop cluster

Cloudera manager provides dynamic resource pool configuration.

Using the configuration, i can restrict application number to specific user

This figure is shows like this

I set that mcha can only use one application.

[image]

But mcha can be execute more than one application

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you refresh the Dynamic Resource Pool after changing the pool configuration? You can check the allocation file(ResourceManager -> processes -> fair-scheduler.xml) to make sure that.